# The method zoomToMapObject(ev.target) doesn't zoom to USA in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using amCharts to show a World Map, and I have this code for when the user clicks on a country:

```
    var groupData = [
        {
            "name": "America",
            "color": "#7DB378",
            "data": [{
                "title": "USA",
                "id": "US",
                "customData": "Data 1"
            }, {
                "title": "Mexico",
                "id": "MX",
                "customData": "Data 2"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Europe",
            "color": "#1AE5B9",
            "data": [{
                "title": "Spain",
                "id": "ES",
                "customData": "Data 3"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Asia",
            "color": "#193387",
            "data": [{
                "title": "China",
                "id": "CN",
                "customData": "Data 4"
            }]
        }
    ];
    var excludedCountries = ["AQ"]; // Exclude Antarctica
    // Create a series for each group, and populate the above array
    groupData.forEach(function (group) {
        var series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
        series.name = group.name;
        series.useGeodata = true;
        var includedCountries = [];
        group.data.forEach(function (country) {
            includedCountries.push(country.id);
            excludedCountries.push(country.id);
        });
        series.include = includedCountries;
        series.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
        series.setStateOnChildren = true;
        var seriesHoverState = series.states.create("hover");
        // Country shape properties & behaviors
        var mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
        // Events
        mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
            // zoom to an object
            ev.target.series.chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
        });
    });
```

This code works fine for all countries except the USA. When clicking on it, it doesn't zoom, just centers a bit the World Map and that's it. Why is this only failing to zoom in the USA? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you confusing the code US with USA maybe?

Comment: I've tried with both "id": "US" and "id: "USA" and it doesn't work. What do you suggest?